# Resolve 2D Collisions

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision-detection

I am making a game and can detect collisions. I need to now resolve them. What I want is the overlap x and y so that I can negate it. Shapes to get overlaps for. Circle & Circle. Circle & Rectangle. **Note** Rotation isn't needed.

There are some answers on stack overflow but none of them are what I want. I simply need overlap x and y and thats it.

Comment: Can you use Intersection Observer? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Here is a great resource to [learn](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7wAPgl1JVvUEb0dIygHzO4698tmcwLk9) from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AABB vs AABB

I remember struggling about this a few years ago while making one of my first games that involved a little physics. I couldn't find anything about it on internet so I made my own algorithm.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/Raynobrak/Charbrary/blob/master/source/Charbrary/Physics/AABB.cpp) in the function `AABB::detectCollision()`. This function detects the overlap and the side of collision between 2 AABBs. I know, it's C++ and not JS but I'm sure you'll be able to "translate" it to JS.

Keep in mind that detecting collisions without taking into account the velocity of the 2 objects will never be extremely precise and will not work at high speeds.

### Circle vs Circle

For circles, it's much more simple.

Let's say you have 2 intersecting circles : A "fixed" one `A` and a moving one `B`.

The overlap between 2 circles is computed by calculating the distance between them and substracting the sum of their radius to it :

`overlap = magnitude(A.pos - B.pos) - (A.radius + B.radius)`

And the collision normal (direction towards which the collision needs to be resolved) is computed by normalizing the delta between the 2 circles :

`direction = normalize(B.pos - A.pos) // An arrow pointing from A to B`

And you move `B` out of `A` by adding to the position of `B` the direction scaled by the overlap.

`B.position += direction * overlap`

Comment: Oops I just saw that you were looking for AABB vs Circle and not AABB vs AABB. Sorry, I didn't read the question correctly